# Annuity : yearly to monthly

Tags: finance

Kenton borrows $250,000 on January 1, 2012 to be repaid in 12 annual installments at an effective annual rate of interest of 12%. The first payment is due on January 1, 2013. Instead of annual payment he decides to make monthly payments equal to one-twelfth the annual payment beginning on February 1, 2013. Determine how many months will be needed to pay off the loan. (Ans : 129.381291)

Anyone know how to solve this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following that would be to use the annuity formula

$239641 = 3363*\dfrac{(1-\frac{1}{(1+r)^t})}{r}$

$\frac{1}{(1+r)^t} = 0.294671$ with r = 0.009489.

$(1+r)^t = 3.393617$

Taking log

$t \times ln(1.009489) = ln(3.393617)$

$t = \frac{ln(3.393617)}{ln(1.009489} = 129.3826$

Comment: If the interest become monthly, aren't it suppose 12% / 12 ? how u get the r = 0.009489?

Comment: You should take care of compounding and hence it is not simple division but $(1.12)^{\frac{1}{12}} - 1 = 0.009489$

Comment: from line 2, how is the equation come from? I calculated 1 - (239641/3363 x r) but the answer is not 0.294671. Is it the # of significant problem?

Comment: Yes you are correct, if it is assumed that the first payment is paid on the 1st of Jan 2013, then the number of months is 119.  If it is not paid on the 1st of Jan  2013, then use the  loan value = 250000 and then you would get  129.38.  I believe the text book assumes that the first payment is not paid.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to solve my question. :)

Comment: You are welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

I misread the question and have revised

He makes the annual payment on 1/1/2013  and then starts paying monthly thereafter.

the annual payment:

$250,000 = P\sum_\limits{n=1}^{12} (1.12)^{-n}\\
250,000 = P \frac {(1 - 1.12^{-12})}{0.12}\\
P = 250,000 \frac {0.01}{1-1.12^{-12}}\\
P = 40,359$

after making his first months payment he owes

$250,000 \frac {1-1.12^{-11}}{1-1.12^{-12}} = 239,640$

and he will be paying $\frac {40359}{12} = 3363$ per month

$239,640 = 3363\sum_\limits{n=1}^k (1.12)^{\frac {k}{12}}\\
71.25 = \frac {1 - 1.12^{\frac {-k}{12}}}{(1.12)^{\frac 1{12}} - 1}\\
1-71.25(1.12^\frac{1}{12} - 1) = (1.12)^{\frac {-k}{12}}\\
\ln 0.324 = \frac {-k}{12}\ln 1.12\\
119.368 = k$

But $k$ doesn't start counting until one year has passed

$131$ months

Comment: May i know what is the purpose of line 9? Its 250000 x ( a angle n-1 / a angle n).

Comment: The first payment of 40359 has both principal and interest.  The interest is (.12*250000) = 30000.  So principal component of the first payment is 40359 - 30000 = 10359.  For the second annuity the loan value is 250000 - 10359 = 239641

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to solve my question. :)